# First attempt at making a sobel edge detection filter in c

Tags: c, array, image, integer

I made a borders filter in C. It works properly, but I think it could be optimized and better designed; the formatting is abysmal. It uses too many lines for the border cases and has too many variables.

**Basic Color Struct**

```
    typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

**Sobel edge filter**

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //sobel operator
    int gy[3][3] = {{-1,-2,-1},{0,0,0},{1,2,1}};
    int gx[3][3] = {{-1,0,1},{-2,0,2},{-1,0,1}};
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    for(int n = 0; n < height; n++) // loop to check every pixel
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < width; k++)
        {
            // variables to use later
            int eqblue, eqred, eqgreen;
            int h = 0;
            int t = 0;
            int j = -1;
            int p = -1;
            float xred, xblue, xgreen, yred, yblue, ygreen;
            xred = xblue = xgreen = yred = yblue = ygreen = 0;
            int widx = 3;
            int hghtx = 3;
            // conditionals for border cases
            if(n == 0)
            {
            p = 0;
            hghtx = 2;
            h = 1;
            }
            if(n == height - 1)
            {
            p = -1;
            hghtx = 2;
            }
            if(k == 0)
            {
            j = 0;
            widx = 2;
            t = 1;
            }
            if(k == width - 1)
            {
            j = -1;
            widx = 2;
            }
            for(int u = 0; u < hghtx; u++) // matrix of pixels around the main pixel using the conditionals gathered before
                for(int i = 0; i < widx; i++)// using sobel operator
                {
                 xgreen = xgreen + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtGreen * gx[u + h][i + t];
                 xred = xred + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtRed * gx[u + h][i + t];
                 xblue = xblue + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtBlue * gx[u + h][i + t];
                 ygreen = ygreen + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtGreen * gy[u + h][i + t];
                 yblue = yblue + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtBlue * gy[u + h][i + t];
                 yred = yred + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtRed * gy[u + h][i + t];
                }
            //checks if the new color value surpasses 255
            eqred = sqrt((pow(xred, 2) + pow(yred, 2))) + 0.5;
            eqblue = sqrt((pow(xblue, 2) + pow(yblue, 2))) + 0.5;
            eqgreen = sqrt((pow(xgreen, 2) + pow(ygreen, 2))) + 0.5;
            if(eqgreen > 255)
                eqgreen = 255;
            if(eqblue > 255)
                eqblue = 255;
            if(eqred > 255)
                eqred = 255;
            //stores color in the temp array
            temp[n][k].rgbtBlue = eqblue;
            temp[n][k].rgbtRed = eqred;
            temp[n][k].rgbtGreen = eqgreen;
        }
    }
        // changes the original image to the filtered one
    for(int n = 0; n < height; n++)
        for(int k = 0; k < width; k++)
        image[n][k] = temp[n][k];
}
```

**Imput**

[image]

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: As you're aware that "the formatting is abysmal", then why not pass it through (e.g.) GNU Indent before presenting it for review?  You're more likely to get good answers if you make it easier for reviewers!

Comment: BTW, we're missing a definition of `BYTE` - I'm guessing from the 0-255 range that it's a typedef for `uint8_t` from `<stdint.h>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## General Observations

We could provide a better review if the calling functions were included and any headers (`math.h`, etc.) were included.

The code is not portable, variable length arrays were made optional to compiler developers as of C11. The code will not compile on some systems.

Declare the variables as they are needed rather than at the top of logic blocks.

## Possible Alignment issues

With the current declaration of `RGBTRIPLE` the struct is only 3 bytes, this is an odd size. The `packed` attribute is not necessarily [considered safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568432/is-gccs-attribute-packed-pragma-pack-unsafe).

It might be better to make the struct a field in a union where the other type is `uint32_t`. You might also want to add a padding BYTE to the struct.

## Magic Numbers

This code contains the Magic Number `255`:

```
            if (eqgreen > 255)
                eqgreen = 255;
            if (eqblue > 255)
                eqblue = 255;
            if (eqred > 255)
                eqred = 255;
```

It might be better to create a symbolic constant for them to make the code more readble and easier to maintain. These numbers may be used in many places and being able to change them by editing only one line makes maintenance easier.

Numeric constants in code are sometimes referred to as [Magic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), because there is no obvious meaning for them. There is a discussion of this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad).

As a side note, the `then` clause and `else` clause of `if` statements have a tendency to grow, so it is always safer to make them compound statements by default:

#define MAX_RBG 255

```
            if (eqgreen > MAX_RBG)
            {
                eqgreen = MAX_RBG;
            }
            if (eqblue > MAX_RBG)
            {
                eqblue = MAX_RBG;
            }
            if (eqred > MAX_RBG)
            {
                eqred = MAX_RBG;
            }
```

The above code could possibly be shortened using conditional assignments:

```
            eqgreen = (eqgreen > MAX_RBG)? MAX_RBG : eqgreen;
```

## Complexity

The function `edges()` is too complex (does too much). There are multiple methods to determine complexity, one uses the number of lines in a function another might be the number of levels of indentation. The `edges()` function is 74 lines of code and there are at least 4 levels of indentation. Lines of code are used because any function larger than a single screen is very difficult to understand and maintain.

There is also a programming principle called the Single Responsibility Principle that applies here. The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.

Some things to consider are Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY code) and breaking the code into smaller functions.

This code should probably be a function due to the complexity:

```
            for (int u = 0; u < hghtx; u++) // matrix of pixels around the main pixel using the conditionals gathered before
                for (int i = 0; i < widx; i++)// using sobel operator
                {
                    xgreen = xgreen + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtGreen * gx[u + h][i + t];
                    xred = xred + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtRed * gx[u + h][i + t];
                    xblue = xblue + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtBlue * gx[u + h][i + t];
                    ygreen = ygreen + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtGreen * gy[u + h][i + t];
                    yblue = yblue + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtBlue * gy[u + h][i + t];
                    yred = yred + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtRed * gy[u + h][i + t];
                }
            //checks if the new color value surpasses 255
            eqred = sqrt((pow(xred, 2) + pow(yred, 2))) + 0.5;
            eqblue = sqrt((pow(xblue, 2) + pow(yblue, 2))) + 0.5;
            eqgreen = sqrt((pow(xgreen, 2) + pow(ygreen, 2))) + 0.5;
            if (eqgreen > 255)
                eqgreen = 255;
            if (eqblue > 255)
                eqblue = 255;
            if (eqred > 255)
                eqred = 255;
            //stores color in the temp array
            temp[n][k].rgbtBlue = eqblue;
            temp[n][k].rgbtRed = eqred;
            temp[n][k].rgbtGreen = eqgreen;
```

in fact just the nested `for` loops could be a function.

While I generally don't recommend writing macros, to reduce the repetitive nature of the code this code could be a macro or a function:

```
        eqred = sqrt((pow(xred, 2) + pow(yred, 2))) + 0.5;
```

that way if you need to change how that calculation is done you only need to edit the code once rather than 3 times.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add a few things to pacmaninbw's great answer:

- `__attribute__((packed))` is not doing anything here. Just remove it.
- Instead of `sqrt(pow(xred, 2), pow(yred, 2))`, you can write [`hypotf(xred, yred)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/hypot). `hypot()` takes the square root of the sum of its arguments squared, and the `f` makes it work in `float` precision, as `double` is unnecessarily precise here.

Comment: Didn't know about the `hypot` family of functions, thanks!